# How can i get all week days for a year by defining a day?

Tags: php

I am trying using php , something like this which is in the picture.

[image]

I have a drop down to select a day and check boxes for checking the weeks. if i select a day as **Sunday** and check  weeks as **1,2,4** then it should get all the sundays of the weeks **1,2,4** for whole year or if i select day as **Monday** and check week as **1,2,3,4,5** then i should get all mondays for the whole year by selected weeks so how can i do using php , i am bit confused with the start.

I took this php code from stack and im trying out

> PHP Code:

```
 function getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates($start, $end, $weekday = 0)
 {

     $weekdays = "Sunday";
     $arr_weekdays=explode(",", $weekdays);
     $weekday = $arr_weekdays[$weekday];
     if(!$weekday)
         die("Invalid Weekday!");

         $start= strtotime("+0 day", strtotime($start) );
         $end= strtotime($end);
         $dateArr = array();
         $friday = strtotime($weekday, $start);
         while($friday <= $end)
         {
             $dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);
             $friday = strtotime("+1 weeks", $friday);
         }
         $dateArr[] = date("Y-m-d", $friday);
         return $dateArr;

 }

 $dateArr = getDateForSpecificDayBetweenDates("2015-01-01", "2015-12-12", 0);

 print_r($dateArr);
```

I need only the year particular selected day and selected weeks dates.

Comment: What did you try? Show us some code, so we can try to help you. We can't write code from scratch for you.

Comment: Week 1, 2, 3 and so forth do refer to the week of a single month or is it the week of the year?

Comment: week for the whole year

Comment: Your comment to my answer suggest that this information is completely wrong. Looks like yo are wanting to select the week of a month (1-5) and NOT the week of the year (1-53).

Comment: you are correct, i need for whole year weeks as example jan = 1,2,3,4,5 feb = 1,2,3,4 mar = 1,2,3,4,5 ... etc